# how to include "global" files in gradle

Tags: groovy, gradle

I have multiple projects with their own `build.gradle` and `settings.gradle`.
i want to add a "global" file which is named also `build.gradle` (or some other name, it dosent matter) to **one** of the projects,  my question is: how do i include the new file from all the other projects (`build.gradle` or `setting.gradle` files) ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I don't think you can do this for `settings.gradle`, but you can load other `build.gradle` files readily enough with

```
apply from: "$rootDir/../OtherProject/path/to/your.gradle"
```

this particular example would assume your projects root directories are contained in a single directory.

Of course because you are loading it raw between projects, non of the definitions from OtherProject/settings.gradle would be loaded, so references may fail in the loaded file unless it is truly global in nature.

However, you might want to instead consider using [a multiproject build](https://docs.gradle.org/current/userguide/multi_project_builds.html) and restructuring your projects in a way that groups them more logically together rather than hard hacking build scripts between disparate projects.

Also, if you're trying to share common tasks etc between projects, consider converting them to a plugin and including that in each project that needs the functionality.

**EDIT**: Showing linking between projects

To access global values, you use `ext`. See the [ext gradle docs](https://docs.gradle.org/current/dsl/org.gradle.api.plugins.ExtraPropertiesExtension.html) for more examples.

Proj1/build.gradle:

```
apply from: "$rootDir/../Proj2/build.gradle"

task printX << {
    # this is the full syntax
    println project.ext.x

    # however, anything on project.ext becomes global too, so you
    # can reference it directly as just "x"
    println "x[a] = ${x['a']}"
    println x['b']

    # showing it's just the map we expect
    def keysOfX = x.keySet()
    println keysOfX
}
```

Proj2/build.gradle:

```
ext {
    x = [a: 1, b: 2]
}
```

Running the task:

```
> cd Proj1
> gradle printX
:printX
{a=1, b=2}
x[a] = 1
2
[a, b]

BUILD SUCCESSFUL

Total time: 2.894 secs
```

Comment: For now i just want to handle the dependencies, in the global build.gradle file i want to declare  a Map<String,String> variable named "x". which will have all the jars  like this: commons_codec: "commons-codec:commons-codec:1.5".  Now, from the other build.gradle i want to adrress x, how can i address it? it throws an error that it dosent know x

Comment: I've added some code with various examples, and linked the `ext` docs for you to do further reading

Comment: @Avra glad I could be of assistance